# What preposition should I use “in” or “on”?

Tags: prepositions, usage

I'm not quite sure about the use of preposition in the sentence below.

Should I write

> A is located **on** the north of B

or

> A is located **in** the north of B

Comment: It would be *A is located **to** the north of B*.

Comment: @WS2 Surely more context is needed. Of the sentences *I live in the north of the United States* and *I live to the north of the United States*, only one is true for me, but both are grammatical. *On* doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @Anonym I merely answered the OP's question. *In* means *inside of*. So if you live *in* the north of the United States, you live *inside the northern part*. *To* the north of, means *outside but on the northern side of the United States*.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "A is farther north than B", then you don't need a preposition, but if you want to use one, then use *to*:

> The USA is north of Mexico. Canada is even farther (to the) north.

If you mean "A is in the north part of B", then use *northern* (for large geographic areas):

> The Yukon is in northern Canada.

For smaller areas, such as a public park:

> The pond is north of the park. (It is outside the park.)
>   The pond is at the north end of the park. (It is inside the park.)

Comment: Your second construction only works for large geographical areas. If doesn't work if B is, say, a public park.

Comment: @TonyK Thanks; that's a good point. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is A within B?

If yes, you can use the latter, e.g. The Arctic [A] is in the north of Earth [B].

Otherwise, if A is not within B, you proceed as WS2 has suggested.

In no circumstance (that I can think of) would you use 'on', since you can't be 'on' north.

Comment: 'The Arctic is in the north of Earth' sounds awful.

Comment: "The Arctic is in the north of Earth" does sound odd, but "Paris is in the north of France" doesn't sound as odd.